# Interpreting image pull log messages in order to visualise image pull latency in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking at the Kubernetes logs we see in our log aggregation tool (Splunk, but not important), and I'm trying to visualise image pull speeds over the day. message that appears in the logs is something like:

Successfully pulled image "registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.10" in 1.100152244s

The value 1.100152244s is a string so obviously doesn't work for visualisation. The string itself can appear in multiple formats:

1.100152244s
4m4.004131504s
64.10064ms

Silly question but what units do we see here after the period? Are these nanoseconds?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: At the time of writing I am not an expert on Kubernetes internals nor do I have any knowledge about Go. (However, I am familiar with the general functioning of K8s components and also with high/low level programming languages...) After about 10 min of research I've gained satisfactory answers:

**Question**

> what units do we see here after the period? Are these nanoseconds?

**Short answer**

The short answer lies in [time.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/time.go#L644).

**Long answer**

The Kubernetes event regarding "*Successfully pulled image <image-name> in <time>*" is generated by the `kubelet` component. *Kubelet* is basically responsible for managing (the life cycle of) pods and their containers. It generates [events](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.24/pkg/kubelet/events/event.go#L40) for various stages of the container's execution, including the `image pulling`. Thus the event you mentioned is generated by the *kubelet* during the image pulling stage of container execution. (At least I knew that part already).

You seem to have a kubelet <= release-1.24 in use. The corresponding event is generated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.24/pkg/kubelet/images/image_manager.go#L156):

```golang
..., fmt.Sprintf("Successfully pulled image %q in %v", container.Image, time.Since(startTime)), ...
```

The duration string comes from the `time.Since(startTime)` (`Duration`) stament. The `fmt.Sprintf` calls the [`func (d Duration) String() string`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/time.go#L644) method on that Duration value, which appears to produce a string output according to the following criteria:

- If the duration is less than one second, it is displayed with smaller units such as "12.345µs" or "678ns".
- If the duration is between one second and one minute, it is displayed in seconds, such as "5s" or "42.123456s".
- If the duration is between one minute and one hour, it is displayed in minutes and seconds, such as "3m45s" or "59m59s".
- If the duration is more than one hour, it is displayed in hours, minutes, and seconds, such as "1h42m" or "12h34m56s".

Maybe you can develop suitable patterns in Splunk to transform this format into the desired time unit for visualization (using if-else conditions may also help, e.g. value includes "h", "m" and "s"? then use the regex `(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+\.?\d*)s` to extract values from e.g. "2h10m10.100152244s").

**Side note**

Newer versions of kubelet (> release-1.24) seem to use a slightly different  [log](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.25/pkg/kubelet/images/image_manager.go)

```golang
..., fmt.Sprintf("Successfully pulled image %q in %v (%v including waiting)", container.Image, imagePullResult.pullDuration, time.Since(startTime)), ...
```

e.g.

> Successfully pulled image "xyz" in 8.831719579s (8.831722421s including waiting)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, great explanation. Thanks also for the heads up on the pointer for the log messages changing, I'll ensure the regex caters for that.